# Invalidate local_task cache for a specific entity

Tags: 8, caching

Is there a way to invalidate local_task cache for a specific entity?

The issue is that an additional local task is defined by a different module that has a custom access check. That custom check if only returning TRUE if certain actions have been made by the system. Though it seems that initial cache persists forever (or until the caches are cleared).

This code seems to be able to remove all caches of local_task type, yet only one entry should really be affected (or a couple, depending on the situation).

```
\Drupal\Core\Cache\Cache::invalidateTags(['local_task']);
```

The issue with this code is that it would remove too much of the cached data. Current implementation does know when actions are taken that would change the permission response for that specific local_task item and would be able to run it.

Looking through the **rendered** cache table, it did not seem that entity was mentioned within the tags for local_task cache entry. There might be a way to make sure it is added there and make the local_task be invalidated along with the entity being changed or just invalidation cache tags for that specific entity.

EDIT:
After poking around I was able to determine that custom entity type does not get cache tags added to local_task tabs. Nodes do seems to have it. The question is thus: how to add entity specific cache tags to local_tasks associated with that?

The bad way would be to use the `hook_menu_local_tasks_alter()`, determine that path is one of the suitable ones and then add the correct cache tags as needed.

A better way would be to make sure that these are always added to any of the tasks directly related to the entity type.

Comment: Have you tried to use the cachetag for the specific node? e.g. `\Drupal\Core\Cache\Cache::invalidateTags(['node:1']);` as by triggering that all the relevant caches related to local tasks will probably get rebuilt (I've not tried this but seems fairly logical)

Comment: I am not sure about the nodes, but in current case I am dealing with a custom entity that might not have all of the additional "magic" that is available for nodes. I did try to clear all the cache tags that a set on the entity by default. It did not clear the local_task portion as that one does not have the entity specific tag present, just the general ones.

Comment: Have a go with "your_custom_entity_machine_name:entityid" just incase it may work

Comment: It did not and will not as the custom entity does not seem to have the "entity_id:ID" added to the respective cache table row as a tag. Nodes do get it. I would need to determine what is missing in comparison to Node implementation.